# board firmware update through uefi capsule feature from Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, bios, uefi

I need to update tianocore(uefi bootloader) firmware on SPI-NOR from Linux OS. It could be done using the capsule update feature of Tianocore.

Can anyone provide some pointers/instructions/steps to update board firmware using capsule update from Linux ?

Does Linux kernel 3.12 support this feature ?

Thanks,
Devendra

Answer (score 0):

This interface is not yet included in the Linux kernel, although some versions of possible patches have been posted, and the interface is being discussed. (And since it still is not available in Linux 4.1-rc7, it is of course also not available in 3.12.)

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.efi/5703 is a relevant component, exporting information about which upgradable firmware components exist in the system.

The latest set of patches for enabling a capsule interface starts with this cover-letter: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.efi/5630

Discussions ongoing on the linux-efi mailing list at http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html.